# MySQL - get data immediately when start application or online?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have question about getting data from database.
I have some information in database, and in application i have classes to store
information from database like: user, goals.

**For Example**: I have button daily goals, for user: Mark. When I press this button in my table view I see daily goals for this user Mark.

My question is, get this information and save in some collection in classes when application is starting, or only when I click button dailygoals?

What is the best practice?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Think about the following: If you get it and save it immediatly after the app start, and the user then clicks the button "daily goals" only some minutes or even hours later. How would you be sure that the data you got on startup is still up to date and did not get modified in the database in the meantime?

Comment: @911DidBush This is good point. So, I think that this is answer for my question.